# SQL Server Simple Query

Tags: sql-server

I have this tables on my database

**Users,Courses,Semesters,SelectedCourses**

**Users :** ID,Username,Password,EnterYear

**Courses :** ID,Name

**Semesters :** ID,Code

**SelectedCourses :** ID,SemesterID(FK to Semesters.ID),UserID(FK to Users.ID),CourseID(FK to Courses.ID)

Now, I have ***2 or n*** CourseID and I want to get Users that selected this Courses **together**.

**for example :**

This is my `SelectedCourses` table :

[image]

**Result must be :**

I want to find Users that have CourseID(1) **and** CourseID(2) on their **SelectedCourses** list.

Only **UserID = 1** have this two courses!

Comment: Show us what you have so far! We'll be glad to help you fix your code if you're stuck somewhere - but SO isn't a code-writing service where you just dump your requirements and get the final, working code back - **you** need to show some effort of your own first!

Comment: @marc_s i want to use it only in sql server

Comment: i think,your DB design is not complete.you need one SemesterCourse mapping table.Then you need UserSemeter Mapping table.Then SelectedCourse Table is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT U.UserID
FROM Users U
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT C.CID
                   FROM Course C
                   WHERE C.CId in (1,2) AND 
                   NOT EXISTS  
                   (SELECT S.CID
                    FROM SelectedCourses S
                    WHERE S.CID = C.CID AND
                          S. UserID = U.UserID)
                );
```

For each user we check that there is no course that is not taken by this user.

This works as long as the number of course is within the range of data type.

Comment: i don't understand your code. can you explain more?

Comment: Ok. For each User U, and course C, looking at last two layer. We would first find course C that is not taken by U. Then, for the first layer, we examine if there is course C that is not selected by U. If not,(That is, if the result of last two layer is empty), then we would add U to our result.

Comment: OK. in this query i want to add course (1,2) to check. so where can i add this?

Comment: Now it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
 userId,count(distinct courseId) 
from 
 selectedCourses 
where 
 courseId in (1,2)
group by userId
having count(distinct courseId) > 1
```